# Is there a way to make list processing as fast as np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am currently replacing some code which I wrote with the assumption that the inputs are numpy arrays such that it takes arbitrary lists as input. Unfortunately the solutions I produced so far are substantially slower than the original code. Can someone give advise how I might reach back to the speed of the original solution?

The code is supposed to produce a boolean index for the upper triangular matrix representation. Without input checks and stuff like this this is the meat of the code:

some import and example input:

```
import numpy as np
descriptor = list(range(100))
descriptor_arr = np.array(descriptor)
value = [0, 2, 13, 14, 11, 23, 45, 16]
```

This is my current list based version:

```
def get_idx_slow(descriptor, value):
    ix, iy = np.triu_indices(len(descriptor), 1)
    pattern_in_value = [p in value for p in descriptor]
    return [(pattern_in_value[idx_x] & pattern_in_value[idx_y]) for idx_x, idx_y in zip(ix, iy)]
```

This is the previous array based version:

```
def get_idx_fast(descriptor, value):
    ix, iy = np.triu_indices(len(descriptor), 1)
    selection_x = np.any(np.array([descriptor[ix] == v for v in value]), axis=0)
    selection_y = np.any(np.array([descriptor[iy] == v for v in value]), axis=0)
    return selection_x & selection_y
```

My timing results:

```
%timeit get_idx_slow(descriptor, value)
1.2 ms ± 33.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit get_idx_fast(descriptor_arr, value)
217 µs ± 1.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This may be difficult or impossible. numpy is highly optimized and takes advantage of multiprocessing and/or vector instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the lazy solution, but just converting the list in the slow function to an array, calling the other function, and converting back to a list. It seemed to be reasonably effective.

Update:

```
def get_idx_slow(descriptor, value):
    return get_idx_fast(np.asarray(descriptor), value).tolist()
```

Results:

```
%timeit get_idx_slow_orig(descriptor, value)
892 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit get_idx_slow(descriptor, value)
182 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit get_idx_fast(descriptor_arr, value)
150 µs ± 1.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, I might try to get away of this, if there is no other fast solution. The whole idea of using lists instead of arrays here is of course to avoid arrays of arbitrary objects, but np.array works on surprisingly many variants here... Will leave this open in case some optimized solution appears